# How can I make some classes unavailable outside my static lib for iOS programming?

Tags: ios, static

I want my lib users can only use some of my lib's APIs,while other APIs only available in my lib but not available outside of the lib.Can somebody pls tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your public classes and the methods for those classes should be listed in the public headers in the build phase. Keep the rest in private headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take some steps to make it hard for your user to use your private APIs:

- Don't give your user the header file for a private class.
- Declare private methods of a public class in a category.  (Put the method implementations in your main class implementation to avoid needing special linker flags.)  Don't give the user the header file that declares the category.
- Put your instance variables in your `@implementation`, not your `@interface`.

You cannot, however, make it impossible for your user to access your private APIs.  Because of the way Objective-C works, the names of all classes and methods can be extracted from the library file ([check out the `class-dump` program](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/)), or even looked up at runtime (using the [Objective-C runtime API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)).

You can even access Apple's private APIs this way.  They will keep you out of the App Store if you do, but you can compile, run, and distribute private-API-using apps using ad-hoc or enterprise distribution.  If there were a mechanism for completely blocking the use of private APIs, surely Apple would be using it.

Comment: category methods are not compatible with static libraries

Comment: @psoft you can use category methods, you just need to link with the `-ObjC` or `-force_load` options.

Comment: I stand corrected, maybe I should have thought so before striking an answer from a guy at 21.5K :)

Comment: If you put the method declarations in a category but put the method implementations in your main class implementation, you don't have to use special linker flags.  I have clarified my answer.